# Перемещение файлов cmd, bat, Batch

Tags: cmd, bat

Тупой вопрос специально для 2-ух часов ночи, bat не знает где он запущен(С:\123\123\bat.bat), ему надо копировать файл 12321.bat из C:\123\123\123\ в C:\123\123\, как ему это сделать не зная полного пути? Bat должен запускаться из любого места и чётко копировать файл из /123/ в /

Кхм, мне надо что бы bat-ник перешёл из папки в которой запущен в папку config(Находиться в одной папке вместе с ним) и копировал(перенёс) оттуда файл start.bat назад в папку в которой был запущен

Comment: *bat не знает где он запущен* Знает. Всегда. Ему передаётся разобранная строка его параметров запуска, где параметр `%0` - это его собственное имя. Из которого элементарно выделяются и диск, и каталог, и имя, хоть вместе, хоть по отдельности (см. `SET /?`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать относительные пути.

```
cd 123
copy 12321.bat ..\12321.bat
```